# Python GUI Tkinter how to stop a script after pressing Start button

Tags: python, tkinter, pyautogui

im new to programming in python but i made a simple GUI using Tkinter that has two Buttons, Start and Quit. When i press the Start button, the GUI freezes and i cant press the Quit button anymore ... how can i fix that ?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time

def running():
    while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png', confidence = 0.9) != None:
            print("I can see it")
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print("I am unable to see it")
            time.sleep(1)

def help():
    filewin = Toplevel(root, padx=50,pady=50)
    information = Label(filewin, text="App made by ..... you can close the app after starting it by pressing the key Q")
    information.pack()

root = Tk()
root.title("Rename me later")

menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Help", command=help)
filemenu.add_separator()
menubar.add_cascade(label="Info", menu=filemenu)


frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=30)
frm.pack()


ttk.Label(frm, text="App made by uknown").grid(column=1, row=0)

frm2=ttk.Label(frm, text="").grid(column=0, row=1)
frm2=ttk.Label(frm, text="").grid(column=1, row=1)
frm2=ttk.Label(frm, text="").grid(column=2, row=1)

frm2=ttk.Label(frm, text="").grid(column=0, row=2)
frm2=ttk.Label(frm, text="").grid(column=1, row=2)
frm2=ttk.Label(frm, text="").grid(column=2, row=2)

frm2=ttk.Button(frm, text="Start", command=running).grid(column=0, row=3)
frm2=ttk.Label(frm, text="").grid(column=1, row=3)
frm2=ttk.Button(frm, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).grid(column=2, row=3)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The "running" function blocks the UI thread from processing other input (pressing Quit button), because it is running for a relatively long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try running your `running` function in its own thread so it doesn't block the main thread

```
from threading import Thread


def running():
    ...
    # yadda yadda


def run_thread()
    # tell this thread to call the 'running' function
    th_runner = Thread(target=running, daemon=True)
    th_runner.start()  # start the thread
```

Then modify your button to call the `run_thread()` function instead

```
frm2=ttk.Button(frm, text="Start", command=run_thread).grid(column=0, row=3)
```

Comment: You sir are amazing ! To make a function that executes another function in a thread is amazing ! It worked ! Thank you

Comment: Happy to help - glad it worked for ya